# OrientDB: error storing Date

Tags: java, orientdb

I have experimenting error storing date in the database v.2.2.5.
Here is the code:

```
OrientVertex ov = sm.getGraphdb().getVertex("12:1177");
Date d = new Date(2016, 7, 29);
Date dt =new Date(2016, 7, 29, 12, 0);

ov.setProperty("date", d);
ov.setProperty("datetime", dt);
...
```

when I check in the DB I see:

[image]

but if I store date inside the DB with this:

```
update #12:1177 set fromODBDate = '2016-08-29'
```

I see it in the correct way. 
Somebody know what is wrong?

Thanks
Marcelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
OrientVertex ov = g.getVertex("#12:1177");
ov.setProperty("date", "2016-7-29", OType.DATE);
ov.setProperty("datetime","2016-7-29 12:00:00", OType.DATETIME);
```

This is the output:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

Date d=new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

ov.setProperty("date", d);
```

[image]

Hope it helps.